# PHP echo within form value

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, echo

I'm attempting to echo a div tag within a HTML form value. Im unable to display the contents of the div tag without messing up the form value.

```
<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>
```

Form value...

```
<input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>">
```

What's outputted... (What's echoed inside the form value should be the current longitude and latitude)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Geolocation search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script id="data" type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js" xmlData="data/data.xml"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<div id="controller">
  <label>Search Term:
    <input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>">
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="name">Name</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <input name="Search" type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search">
</div>
<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>

<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML=" " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br> " + position.coords.longitude;  
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there soem other way to echo out the longitude and latitude from the that's loaded within the echo statement?

Comment: I think you need to reread the question and explain it better.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I don't understand... Is that pertinent to my question?

Comment: @OneOfOne I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Dare I ask what is the purpose of having a <div> as the value of an input?

Comment: @AaronSantos Page loads, displays the current longitude/latitude in the value, searches for a match, displays information about your location. It's a weekend project I thought of.

Comment: @Pxlc But that div has no value, no meaning...

Comment: @AaronSantos It will just have to do at the moment. The point is, to have the longitude/latitude from the rest of the code I included with the question to be entered automatically in the form value without manually entering in. http://boomerang.pxlc.me/_old/index.html

Comment: @AaronSantos Can it have a value from the echo?

Comment: @Pxlc The <div> inside the input is not a <div> it's just the value of the input. It's just text. You're not able to getElementById("demo") because "demo" does not exist in the DOM. Just use the id of the input field "term" and use jquery's $("#term").val() to get it's value.

Comment: @AaronSantos Term associates with the location. Demo searches xml for matches from the input field. They are two different things though.Would $("#demo").val() do instead?

Comment: @Pxlc ...Why are you now echoing javascript in the input?(It won't work it's just text, the same as the div!) THINK! Don't echo anything in the input value. Just change the input id from "term" to "demo". If you want more help just open a new question.

Comment: @AaronSantos I don't think that will be feasible. Term searches for the matching "term". Demo finds the location. So something has to be displayed in the text input...

Answer (score 2):

it's the "

change

```
<input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo "<div id='demo'></div>";?>">
```

Comment: It works! I must have missed the double quote. One thing though, all that is echoed is the actual <div> tag not the current location. http://boomerang.pxlc.me/_old/index.html?

Comment: i have no idea what that is.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes around the word demo that are closing your value.

Try:

```
<?php echo "<div id='demo'></div>";?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be <?php echo "<div id='demo'></div>";?> ?

Comment: And that will give it a value? Because right now it just prints out the div tag.

Comment: @Pxlc Maybe I am misunderstanding that particular issue and what you are trying to do. Might be better to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <label>Search Term:
        <input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo '<div id="demo"></div>';?>">
     </label>
```

What i see from the above script is, you used a double quote to represent your attribute value.. and then single quote to handle the php echo value, then used a double quote again inside the div which makes the php code invalid because it stops its reading by the double quote you used. you might as well concatenate your php script or use an escape character for the string to be valid "\"

```
    <label>Search Term:
        <input type="text" id="term" value="<?php echo '<div id=\'demo\'></div>'; ?>" />
    </label>

    <?php echo "<div id='demo'></div>"; ?>
```

And may i just ask... What are you trying to echo out of the value? Is it really the div tag?

Comment: Thank you! Not the div itself. The javascript I provided displays the longitude and the latitude of the current location displayed in the div "demo". That's what I want in the value.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the HTTP headers, which you are sending like above, are telling the browser to expect a file to be downloaded. They are not telling browser to expect HTML content (default). Therefore the content you are sending in an echo is not getting displayed.

Both won't work together correctly although I'm sure you can find any work around but the point is that you only need those echo's while debugging so you can disable the mentioned header call while debugging and once everything is set, enable that again so file can download.